# A question about linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T:$\Bbb C^2 \to \Bbb C^2$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(z,w)=(z+iw,w-iz)$, where $i^2=-1$. Find a linear transformation $S:\Bbb C^2 \to \Bbb C^2$ such that $S^3=T$

Answer (score 1):

We have easily 
$$T^2=2T$$
so we can take for example

$$S=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3] 4} T$$
and you have the desired equality.

Comment: How did you find out that $T^2=2T$?

Comment: Just calculate $T(T(z,w))=T(z+iw,w-iz)$.

Comment: I mean I know I only need to calculate to get $T^2 = 2T$, I am just curious why you know you should do that but I didn't realize the property of $T$

Comment: Write T in a matrix form with basis 1,i. You shall immediately see the above property of T

Comment: @user236626 It is the sixth sense and you will get it after a hard work and a  good experience:-)